# Помогите разобраться с кодировкой в MySQL и PHP

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте уважаемые профессионалы.

Я только начал изучать PHP и MySQL и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Сделал пару таблиц в БД, кодировка таблиц и текстовых полей везде стоит utf8_general_ci.
Но при запросе к БД и выводе на экран вместо кириллицы выводятся знаки вопроса.
Проверка кодировки на странице говорит, что кодировка latin 1 ???.
Почему так, ведь везде в настройках сервера (у меня стоит Dewnwer), таблиц и текстовых полей в таблицах стоит utf8_general_ci ?

При вот таком запросе к таблице в БД -

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mytest2');
    
printf("Изначальная кодировка: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($connection));
echo '<br>';

$result = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles`" );

    while ( ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) )
    {
        print_r ($record);
        echo '<hr>';
    }

mysqli_close($connection);
```

на выходе получаю вот это -

[image: Скрин страницы]

В консоли phpMyAdmin, в самой таблице, всё выглядит корректно -

[image: Скрин консоли phpMyAdmin]

Прилагаю скрины с настройками таблиц и настройками сервера -

[image: Настройка кодировки в таблице]

[image: Настройка кодировки сервера]

Посмотрел в значениях переменных сервера - вроде всё тоже в UTF-8, кроме одной переменной :

[image: Значения переменных]

Может таки здесь собака зарыта ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пересмотрел похожие темы здесь, но не совсем понимаю - как c этим бороться!
Может кто поможет дельным советом?
Буду весьма благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

В Denwer не стоит использовать root пользователя, лучше создать нового пользователя.
Цитата из документации с сайта Denwer:

> **3.10. После установки пакета с PHP 5 на всех моих форумах(phpBB и vBulleting) вместо русских букв-стоят знаки вопроса, смена кодировки
> не помогает. Моя версия SQL: 5.0.18 Что делать?**
>
> Используйте для форума отдельную базу данных и /отдельного
> пользователя БД, отличного от root/! Проблема возникает только в
> случае, если соединяться с базой под пользователем root (это известная
> особенность MySQL). Создать базу и пользователя можно, например, при
> помощи скрипта http://localhost/Tools/addmuser/
>
> **4.1. Проблема с кодировкой MySQL 4.1: из БД извлекаются «вопросики» вместо русских букв**
>
> MySQL 4.1 на внутреннем уровне работает с кодировкой UTF8 и
> перекодирует результат в требуемую форму (в нашем случае windows-1251)
> непосредственно перед передачей его клиенту (т.е. скрипту). В
> некоторых случаях оказывается, что кодировка клиента (скрипта) «не
> доходит» до MySQL. Соответственно,
> сервер передает «вопросики». Можно применить одно из следующих
> решений.
>
> - Вписать в скрипт что-то вроде: mysql_query(«SET NAMES cp1251»). Это надо делать сразу же после подключения к MySQL. Проблема исчезнет.
> - Вписать init-connect="SET NAMES cp1251" в /usr/local/mysql4/my.cnf (кто не видит этого файла, пусть изучает Windows, читает FAQ и думает
>   головой) и перезапустить MySQL. Однако это сработает только для
>   соединений, которые проходят НЕ под root-пользователем. Скрипты,
>   коннектящиеся к базе под root, по-прежнему будут получать неверную
>   кодировку. Лучше всего будет все-таки завести новую базу и
>   пользователя через http://localhost/denwer/Tools/addmuser/ и забыть о
>   проблеме.
> - Чтобы диагностировать проблему, выполните в скрипте запрос SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'. Как видите, кодировка неверная:
>   character_set_client=latin1. Это из-за того, что я подключился к базе
>   под root. Если теперь подключусь под не-root пользователем – все будет
>   нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Всё попробовал. Описал в ответе ниже. Результат - тот же! Что не так? Может использовать другой сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Создал нового пользователя "admin" и под него новую базу данных.
Таблицы всё те же.

[image: Скрин 1]

В общем, код получился такой -

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'admin', '123', 'admin');

mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");    

$result = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM `comments`" );

    while ( ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) )
    {
        print_r ($record);
        echo '<hr>';
    }

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Но проблема всё так же и осталась!

[image: Скрин 2]

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Исследуйте получаемые данные в шестнадцатиричных кодах. Ибо сейчас совершенно неясно, где косячит - может, это на веб-странице неверная кодировка отображения, например.

Comment: Ой, эт Вы совсем уж хорошо обо мне думаете! Я ж вроде написал, что только начал изучать программирование... То, что Вы предложили - для меня вообще пока темный лес.